# Bottom align after pull-right

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h2>Some header text</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="div1" class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="pull-right">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePageSizeAction", "myController"))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <small>Page Size</small>
                @Html.DropDownList("pageSize", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
            }
        </div>
        <div id="div2" class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px">
            @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }),
                        new PagedListRenderOptions()
                        {
                            MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 3,
                            DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true,
                            PageCountAndCurrentLocationFormat = "Page {0} of {1}",
                        })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the output:
[image]

I want to align the PagedListPager to bottom beside the DropDownList like this:
[image]

I tried to set `div1` style to `position:relative` and `div2` style to `position:absolute; bottom:0` but didn´t work.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle with your html rendered. Working fine with bootstrap classes http://jsfiddle.net/455SX/

Comment: Morpheus, I´m very sorry for the question, i found an error in my css (margin:0) in another NuGet packaged I have installed. You helped me a lot with your jsfiddle. Should I delete the question? Thank you very much!!

Comment: @OswaldoMilet Answer your own question, then, select it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Morpheus comment I looked for the difference in his jsfiddle example and mine, so I found an error (margin:0) in my css classes.

So, sorry for the wrong question.